# Why are the VectorOfKeyPoint and Mat arrays getting overwritten by the new SIFT detector results?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, visual-studio, emgucv

During execution of `PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static VectorOfKeyPoint _templateKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
        static Mat _templateDescriptor = new Mat();
        VectorOfKeyPoint[] templateKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint[2];
        Mat[] templateDescriptor = new Mat[2];
        Bitmap[] croppedImage = new Bitmap[2];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Load("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg");
            pictureBox2.Load("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg");
            croppedImage[0] = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
            croppedImage[1] = (Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image.Clone();
        }

        private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var processTemplate = ProcessTemplate(croppedImage[i].ToImage<Gray, byte>());
                    templateKeyPoints[i] = processTemplate.tempKeyPoints;
                    templateDescriptor[i] = processTemplate.tempDescriptor;
                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                }
               
            }
        }        

        public static (VectorOfKeyPoint tempKeyPoints, Mat tempDescriptor)
            ProcessTemplate(Image<Gray, byte> template)
        {
            try
            {
                SIFT detector = new SIFT();
                detector.DetectAndCompute(template, null, _templateKeyPoints, _templateDescriptor, false);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }

            return (_templateKeyPoints, _templateDescriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

- During the first iteration:

  When `templateKeyPoints[0]` and `templateDescriptor[0]` get populated, I get the correct results.
- During the second iteration:

  The new results from `processTemplate.tempKeyPoints` and
  `processTemplate.tempDescriptor` get overwritten to the first
  elements of `templateKeyPoints[i]` and `templateDescriptor[i]`, respectively (not
  as desired) and also get populated to their respective second element (as
  desired). Why is this overwriting occurring please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. This was because I wasn't creating a new `VectorOfKeyPoint` and 'Mat' instance whenever I call `ProcessTemplate()` method. So I moved `VectorOfKeyPoint _templateKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();` and `Mat _templateDescriptor = new Mat();` to the method as follows:

```
        public static (VectorOfKeyPoint tempKeyPoints, Mat tempDescriptor)
            ProcessTemplate(Image<Gray, byte> template)
        {
            VectorOfKeyPoint _templateKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
            Mat _templateDescriptor = new Mat();
            try
            {
                SIFT detector = new SIFT();
                detector.DetectAndCompute(template, null, _templateKeyPoints, _templateDescriptor, false);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }

            return (_templateKeyPoints, _templateDescriptor);
        }
```